# Xamarin Maps iOS Catch Tap on Annotation ( Marker )

Tags: ios, xamarin, maps

i'm working on Xamarin Maps ( I'm using Forms with a CustomRenderer) on iOS. I'm putting some Pins on my Map, everything works fine until I decide to don't show any Baloon or View on my Pin when i Tap it. I just need to catch the event:

```
MKMapView.DidSelectAnnotationView
```

without display any title or subtitle. **But the event is called only when i set a title and a subtitle**. ***So, there is a way to put a pin that not display any baloon at Tap and just catch the Tap Event?***
I tried to use

```
anView.CanShowCallout = false;
```

But nothing happen, the baloon is always showed. I'm using a ClusteringManager and this is the Source code: https://pastebin.com/A6tZAQzc .

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, i was putting anView.CanShowCallout = false; Only on cluster and not on the single maker. My bad!